# jQuery, js, listener when div lose class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very unusual problem and I do not know if it is possible to solve it using jQuery.

1. When someone clicks on the page (on element .tc-lightbox-wrap)
2. When the any div loses class (.tc-hidden)
3. Move the screen (center screen) to this div

I must use MutationObserver?

I try using:

```
$('.cart').bind('.tc-hidden .tc-hidden', function() { });
```

but this is not working good with addEventListener 'click'.

Probably it is my fault that it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tc-lightbox-wrap").click(function() {
    }); 
});
```

It works, but I do not know how to find out which div has lost class and how to do it by scrolling the screen

I have no idea.

Comment: Why do you need to know when a `div` loses a class?  That seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  It sounds like you just to use jquery's `event-delegation approach`.  Take a look at [jQuery's on() method with selectors](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  The answer might be (for example) `$('.cart').on('click', '.tc-hidden .tc-hidden', function() { });`

Comment: Dziękuję za Twoją wiadomość. Właśnie element traci klasę, więc pojawia się, a ja wtedy chcę do tego div'a który pojawił się wysłać użytkownika. Sądzisz, że powinienem nie tylko usuwać klasę "hidden" ale też dodawać jakąś, aby było prościej?